# Logistic map bifurcation

Tags: dynamical-systems, bifurcation, chaos-theory

Ok I am trying to do this on matlab, but I need to understand how to find the bifurcation values for logistic map by hand first.

So here is the logistic map:
$$
x_{i+1} = f(x_i) \qquad \text{where} \qquad f(x) = rx(1 - x)
$$

So far, I have found the $x$ values by letting
$$
rx(1 - x) = x
$$
and then
$$
x = 1 - \frac{1}{r}.
$$
And, this is period one.

Now what? Please help me understand this.

Comment: You might want to try google for more efficient ways of calculating  $\delta = 4.6692016091...$ (Feigenbaum's constant). I found a number of original papers by Mitchell J. Feigenbaum too,  also found a  downloadable  Mathematica notebook.

Comment: Yes, if I could get one.

Comment: Here is the Mathematica Link: http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ClassicLogisticMap/

Comment: And a link for the Matlab version: http://lab.fs.uni-lj.si/lasin/wp/IMIT_files/chaotic/Orbit_logistic/orbit_logistic.html

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Here's a Maple version of what you want:
restart; f := rsolve({s(1) = .3, s(n+1) = a*s(n)*(1-s(n))}, s, makeproc); g := proc (n, i) options operator, arrow; eval(f(n), a = i) end proc; t := time(); L := [seq(seq([i, g(k, (1/320)*i)], i = 800 .. 1280), k = 200 .. 300)]; time()-t; plot(L, x = 800 .. 1280, y = 0 .. 1, style = point, symbol = solidcircle, colour = black, symbolsize = 5)

I tried to buy a home version of Matlab, but no dice, so its Maple, sorry.

Comment: you can use free octave instead of Matlab

Answer (score 0):

> I need to understand how to find the bifurcation values for logistic map by hand first.

If you want to understand how to compute periodic points then  after period 1 is period 2 ( period doubling ). 
[image]

Period 2 points can be found by solving equation ( z is on vertical axis) :

$ f(f(z)) = z$

period 3 :

$f(f(f(z))) = z $

and so on.

The next thing is that above image shows only attracting periodic points, not repelling. After doubling are also other cascades.

There are many more things in real iterations, some you can find [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fractals/Iterations_of_real_numbers/r_iterations)

HTH